# Detail in Bertini theorem (II.8.18 in Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In II.8.18 in Hartshorne book about Bertini theorem, $X$ is some non singular closed subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ where $k$ is algebraicaly closed. For a closed point $x\in X$ we set
$$ B_x=\{ \text{hyperlanes } H\,|\,H\supseteq X\text{ or }H\not\supseteq X\text{ but }x\in H\cap X\text{ is not a regular point of }X\cap H\}$$
then we set $\varphi_x:V=\Gamma(\mathbb{P}^n_k,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n_k}(1))\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$ the natural restriction to $X$ following by localization and quotient.

We have that $x\in H\cap X$ iff $\varphi_x(f)\in\mathfrak{m}_x$ (if not: $f$ invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ so locally $H\cap X=\emptyset$)

If $x\in H\cap X$ we have that $x$ regular in $X\cap H$ iff $\varphi_x(f)\neq0$ (so that dimension of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/(f)$ and dimension of $\overline{\mathfrak{m}}_x/\overline{\mathfrak{m}}_x^2$ stay the same)

At the end of the first paragraph is written that $H=V(f)$ is in $B_x$ iff $f\in\ker(\varphi_x)$.

I'm agree with the fact that $f\in\ker(\varphi_x)$ implies that $H\in B_x$: because of what we said above.

***Question***: But I do not understand ***why $H\in B_x$ should imply that $f\in\ker(\varphi_x)$***: the problematic case is if $H=V(f)\supseteq X$. Then, as $X$ is non singular, $x$ will be a regular point of $X\cap H=X$ so that $\varphi_x(f)\neq0$. Hence $f\not\in\ker(\varphi_x)$.

(Hartshorne mentions that $\varphi_x(f)=0\iff H\supseteq X$: there should be some quantifier?... I think the key point is here but I can't get it)

Comment: I think the equivalent relation should be: If $x\in H\cap X$, then $x$ is regular in $X\cap H$ iff $\varphi_x(f)\in \mathfrak{m}_x^2-\{0\}$. Moreover, when $H\supset X$, then $f$ vanishes at $x$, so $f_x=0\in\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. In particular, $\varphi_x(f)=0$.

Comment: Ok, in fact for Hartshorne $\varphi_x$ is $V\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and not $V\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x^2$.

Comment: I should have written $\varphi_x(f)\notin\mathfrak{m}_x^2-\{0\}$ in my first comment. Unfortunately, I can't edit it.

Comment: I was confused by the notation but also I confused $f=0$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ and $f\in\mathfrak{m}_x$: the first is for $V(f)\cap X$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ (which imply that $H\supseteq X$, why...) and the second is for $H\cap X$ is passing through $x$

Comment: For $f=0$ in $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$, by definition this means $f=0$ in $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for some open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$. This is a stronger condition than $f\in\mathfrak{m}_x$. The latter, means that $f=0$ in the residue field, which means exactly the value of function $f$ at a point $x$, say $f(x)$, equals to $0$. Since $H$ is the zeros of $f$, so for a point $x\in X$, we have $x\in H\cap X$ iff $f(x)=0$

Comment: Ok so the equivalence $\varphi_x(f)=0\iff H\supseteq X$ is true (with the notation $\varphi_x:V\to\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$) because if $\varphi_x(f)=0$ then $V(f)\cap X$ contain an open set of $X$ and is closed in $X$, but $X$ is irreducible so that $V(f)\cap X=X$. Thanks for your help!